# Javascript global variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I am running into a strange scope issue with Javascript (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaNpK/1/)):

```
var someGlobal = 3;

function someF() {
    // undefined issue
    alert(someGlobal);
    var someGlobal = 5;
    // Displays 5
    alert(someGlobal);
}

function someF2() {
    // Displays 3, why?
    alert(someGlobal);
}

someF();
someF2();
```

Why doesn't Javascript throws an undefined issue in `someF2()`? How come `someF2()` can access the `someGlobal`, and `someF()` not? How can I make sure a global variable is accessible in a function?

**Remark:**

In both cases, the functions start by calling `alert(someglobal)`, why does one function throw an undefined issue and the other not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`someF` creates a new (locally scoped) variable called `someGlobal` (which masks the global `someGlobal`) and assigns a value to it. It doesn't touch the global `someGlobal` (although cannot access it because there is another variable with the same name in scope).

`var` statements are hoisted, so `someGlobal` is masked for *all* of `someF` (not just after the `var` statement). The value of the local `someGlobal` is `undefined` until a value is assigned to it.

`someF2` access the original (untouched) global `someGlobal`.

Comment: +1 for best answer but describe more that global variable gets overwrite by local variable in function :D

Comment: It doesn't get overwritten, it gets masked.

Comment: well can you give me a little explanation about both! i haven't done research on it! For only that function it gets overwritten or not?

Comment: Are you saying that because someF() declares a local variable called someGlobal after the first alert, this impacts this first alert() by having it throw the undefined issue?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are declaring a local variable with the same name. So it assigns the value to the local variable. Just remove the var from var someGlobal in someF() and it should be fine.

```
var someGlobal = 3;

function someF() {
    // undefined issue
    alert(someGlobal);
    someGlobal = 5; // <-- orignially var someGlobal = 5
    // Displays 5
    alert(someGlobal);
}

function someF2() {
    // Should display 5 now
    alert(someGlobal);
}

someF();
someF2();
```

Answer (score 1):

someF2 displays 3 because it still **is** 3.

In someF() you create a new variable that happens to have the same name as someGlobal. That does not do anything to the original someGlobal, it just creates a new variable **locally** to function someF that goes away when that function ends.

So you have local variables (e.g. created inside someF with var) and global ones.

Comment: Ok, but why do I get an undefined issue in one case and not the other? That's my question.

Comment: I think Quentin has now explained that.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to use both the local and global variable inside `someF` by using `this`.

```
var someGlobal = 3;

function someF() {

    // Displays 3
    alert(someGlobal);
    this.someGlobal = 5;
    someGlobal = 5;
    // Displays 5
    alert(this.someGlobal);
}

function someF2() {
    // Displays 5
    alert(someGlobal);
}

someF();
someF2();
```

​